Can't retrieve cookies with document.cookie (returns empty string)
I am currently trying to build a Django backend with a React frontend.
But I have a problem with my cookies (specifically the csrftoken).
I think the problem is that I can't get the cookie with document.cookie in the console or in javascript with Cookies.get() although the cookies are shown in chrome:
here
This is the response when trying to retrieve the cookies:
here
What is the problem?
Now the httponly tag is already not set like in the image and the samesite attribute is also set to none, so that cant be the problem.

You're using HTTP right (not HTTPS)? What's the value of your CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE setting?

@AbdulAzizBarkat I am actually using HTTPS with CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=True. In the beginning, I tried HTTP with CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False, but it didn't work. That's why I changed to HTTPS because I thought, that might fix my problem, but it didn't.
